# Wind Turbine Generator

Tags: batteries, diodes, motor, dc, generator

Can an unstable and low current supply from a 7V wind turbine dc generator motor charge a 24V lithium-ion battery? If yes, how will it be done?

Comment: 7 V is low, but ideally you should find a 24 V lithium ion charger with MPPT input featuring boost. 17 V would be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Use a boost input battery charger.

I would not recommend using a simple boost DC-DC supply, as that could over-charge the battery.

Comment: Yes or a Boost DC-DC followed by a DC charger recommended for this type of battery.